# Find the flux for the vector field $F =(x^2,y^2,z^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, spheres

Find the flux for the vector field $\vec{F}=(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ across the boundary to the ball given as $$(x-1)^2 +(y+1)^2 +(z-2)^2 \le 4$$
Edit: How much I've done: The center of the sphere is $(1,−1,2)$ (I've sketched it), thus $r(θ,ϕ)=(1+cosθsinϕ, −1+sinθsinϕ, 2+cosϕ)$ . Then to find the normal vector $\vec{N}$ , I've calculated $\frac{∂r(θ,ϕ)}{∂ϕ}=(cosθcosϕ,sinθcosϕ,−sinϕ)$ and $\frac {∂r(θ,ϕ)}{∂θ}=(−sinθsinϕ,cosθsinϕ,0)$ then $\frac{∂r(θ,ϕ)}{∂ϕ} \times \frac{∂r(θ,ϕ)}{∂θ}$, and finally got $(sin2ϕ,sinθsin2ϕ,sinϕcosϕ)$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @MathLover I think that I should either use Divergence theorem or find the normal to the sphere. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Please see this for help - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4006612/how-to-change-variables-in-surface-integral/4006957#4006957

Comment: @MathLover Ok now I've tried the divergence theorem, I got $$2\iiint_K x +y +z \,dV\,$$ where the sphere's volume $\frac{8\pi}{3}$. Can I compute this integral or am I stuck? help please

Comment: @MathLover I have tried without divergence and still got stuck, and I really want to use divergence because I want to learn it, but I have no clue how to start.

Comment: Can you please edit your question (not in comments) to write everything you have tried so far. Based on the link I sent, you should be able to make progress. Only when I see your work, I will know where you are stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120263/discussion-between-math-lover-and-18929371).

Comment: The center of the sphere is $(1, -1, 2 )$, thus $r(\theta, \phi) = (1+cos\theta sin\phi , -1+sin\theta sin\phi , 2+ cos\phi)$ . Then to find the normal vector $\vec{N}$, I've calculated $\frac{\partial r(\theta, \phi)}{\partial \phi} = (cos\theta cos\phi , sin\theta cos\phi , -sin\phi)$ and $\frac{\partial r(\theta, \phi)}{\partial \theta} =(-sin\theta sin\phi , cos\theta sin\phi , 0)$ then  $\frac{\partial r(\theta, \phi)}{\partial \phi} \times  \frac{\partial r(\theta, \phi)}{\partial \theta}$, finally $sin^2 \phi ,sin\theta sin^2\phi , sin\phi cos\phi$. Too long for the chat@MathLover

Comment: Edit your question with the progress please, not comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Divergence Theorem is absolutely the right approach, as all the hypotheses of the theorem hold. You should always prefer to do a volume integral rather than a surface integral. In this case, you might also recognize that
\begin{multline*}
\iiint_K x\,dV = \bar x\, \text{volume}(K), \quad \iiint_K y\,dV = \bar y\, \text{volume}(K), \quad\text{and} \\ \iiint_K z\,dV = \bar z\, \text{volume}(K),
\end{multline*}
where $(\bar x,\bar y,\bar z)$ is the centroid (center of mass) of $K$.
When $K$ is a ball (with uniform density), we all know that its centroid is at its center. Indeed, I would comment that multivariable calculus students should always be on the lookout to apply symmetry arguments.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment why? If there's a mistake, I would like to fix it, and a downvote is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your region is $R: (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-2)^2 \leq  4$.

If you are applying divergence theorem, you need to evaluate $\displaystyle \iiint_R 2(x+y+z) \ dV$

Just to simplify your working, consider the below substitution -

$u = x-1, v = y+1, w = z-2$ and region $R$ transforms to $E: u^2+v^2+w^2 \leq 4$ which is a sphere of radius $2$ centered at the origin. Jacobian for the transformation is $1$.

So the integral becomes $\displaystyle \iiint_E 2(2 + u + v + w) \ dV$. Note that $u, v, w$ are odd functions and due to symmetry, their integral over a sphere centered at the origin will be zero. For example, integral of $u$ over half sphere (for $u \leq 0$) will cancel out with the integral over the other half ($u \geq 0)$.

So the problem reduces to finding $\displaystyle \iiint_E 4 \ dV$ which you know even without the integral.

Comment: A direct symmetry argument obviates the need for substitution. (Many multivariable calculus courses do not treat general changes of variables. I do agree that this one is quite elementary.)

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you for your comments. I am fully aware. Integral of $(x-1), (y+1) $ and $(z-2)$ due to symmetry is zero. That simply leads to $4$ times volume. But I am not sure how familiar OP is with that. Hence my solution. Also I did come across cases with solids cut by planes or a recent one from a student which was an oblique hyperbolic cylinder that become extremely tedious to solve without a substitution.

Comment: My point is that every multivariable calculus student should know the centroid long before the general change of variables theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree with that.